# How to Fire Global.asax's Session_Start Event From Custom HTTP Session State Module?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, session, session-state

I wrote a HTTP Session State Module that handles my custom Session State Provider.
And you know `Session_Start` and `Session_End` will work in `InProc` mode and not in Custom mode.
So I want Global.asax to handle a `Session_Start` method (with my Custom session module and provider) to raise it to some initialisations on my application.

I found [this Article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21156/ASP-NET-HttpModule-for-handling-session-end-with-S) to handle `Sessoin_End` Event in StateServer mode, but what about handling the Start Event?!

My Module's Start Event:

```
public sealed class MyCustomSessionStateModule : IHttpModule
{
    ...

    /*
     * Add a Session_OnStart event handler.
     */
    public static event EventHandler Start
    {
        add
        {
            _sessionStartEventHandler += value;
        }
        remove
        {
            _sessionStartEventHandler -= value;
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

My Web.config Module Configurations:

```
<httpModules>
    <remove name="Session"/>
    <add name="MyCustomSessionStateModule" type="CustomSessionStateServer.MyCustomSessionStateModule" />
</httpModules>
```

My Web.config Provider Configurations:

```
<sessionState  mode="Custom"  customProvider="CustomSessionStateStoreProvider" timeout="20">
    <providers>
        <add name="CustomSessionStateStoreProvider" type="CustomSessionStateServer.CustomSessionStateStoreProvider" />
    </providers>
</sessionState>
```

I wrote my module in a structure that the session_start will fire in AcquireRequestState's Begin Time.

```
/*
 * IHttpModule Member
 */
public void Init(HttpApplication app)
{
     ...

    // Handling OnAcquireRequestState Asynchronously
    app.AddOnAcquireRequestStateAsync(
        new BeginEventHandler(this.app_BeginAcquireState),
        new EndEventHandler(this.app_EndAcquireState));

     ...
}

private IAsyncResult app_BeginAcquireState(object source, EventArgs e, AsyncCallback cb, object extraData)
{
    ...
    if (_rqIsNewSession)
    {
        // Firing Sessoin_Start Event
        _sessionStartEventHandler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

According to [ASP.net Application Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473(v=vs.85).aspx) The Session State must be available on `AcquireRequestState` event. but still i have null Session object in Gloabal.asax's Session_Start.
I wrote this module according to the [Microsoft's .NET 4.5 framework SessionStateModule Source Code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/xsp/system/Web/State/SessionStateModule.cs).

Comment: All the weird capitalisation distracts greatly from the actual question, for me anyway.

Comment: I think you may find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410390/raise-session-onstart-event-from-custom-asp-net-sessionstateprovider-class

Comment: no. it is not my answer. i'm firing Session_Start on a custom HTTP Module not a SessionStateDataStoreProvider.

Comment: Can you clarify the reasons behind what you want to achieve. Why are you using session_start to do application initialization?

Comment: it is a natural behavior of session module to handle session_Start and Session_End. i use it to add some user specific keys to the session object.